# unidentified index on ajax get php file on submission

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Im using AJax to call a php file and get the values, however, on submission, everything works fine but returning unidentified variable from the called php file.

This is my script

```
<script>
function showPrice(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET",'getcurrentpumpprice.php?q='+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

    var pumpprice1 = document.getElementById('pumpprice').value;
    var amount1 = document.getElementById('amount').value; 
    document.getElementById('litre').value = (amount1)  / (pumpprice1);
}
</script>
```

and this is my php code

```
$q = isset($_GET['q']);
$outletid = $session->userinfo['retailoutlet']; 

if($q == 'PMS'){
   $query = "SELECT pms_price FROM ".TBL_RETAIL_OUTLETS." WHERE outlet_id= '$outletid ' ";
    $result = $database->query($query);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $pump_price =  $row['pms_price'];
}

echo '<div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Current Pump Price <span class="required">*</span>
                                                </label>
                                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                                  <input id="pumpprice" name="pumpprice" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" required="required" type="text" value="'.$pump_price.'" readonly="readonly">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

> Im using AJax to call a php file and get the values, however, on
>   submission, everything works fine but returning unidentified variable
>   from the called php file.

**Cause**

> In your case variable `$q` will never be `'PMS'` because you got 
>   `$q = intval($_GET['q']);` so `if($q == 'PMS'){` evaluates false, and  variable `$pump_price` will be undefined
>   always

Example below one evaluates **false** reason `intval()`,

`if($q == 'PMS'){`

then

variable (`$pump_price`) you are using in `echo` will be `undefined variable`

Either you should use `echo` inside your `if` statement

```
if($q == 'PMS'){
       echo 'your html';
}
```

OR

```
if(isset($pump_price)){   
     echo 'your html';  
}
```

Better you validate before querying, also good if you use **PDO**

```
if( isset($_GET['q']) && is_int($_GET['q']) ){

   $q = intval($_GET['q']);

   // your remaining code

}else{

   echo 'invalid input';

}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur seggestion, i put intval when i was debugging and i already removed it, even with that. its still not working. i use if( isset($_GET['q']) ){
$q = isset($_GET['q']);   and use      if($pump_price)  {
echo   ///result  . which is not working

Comment: Your edit doesn't make sense, `$q = isset($_GET['q']);` saves Boolean status

Comment: Ok, now its not giving me any error, but loading to the called php file and returning blank when i submit. but every submission is working file